# Can I somehow repeat HTML snippets when using a GWT UIRenderer?

Tags: gwt

As part of a project we are developing a GWT activity which contains a list of items, each of which (among other things) may contain a list of subitems. It's a bit analogous to what you see on the front page of stack overflow with the message thread summary list and the variable number of tags on each thread summary.

For various reasons we really like using .ui.xml files for declarative layout and I've implemented a cell renderer based upon a UIRenderer with a .ui.xml template file (much like the example here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-custom-cellrenderer). The plan is to hand that to a CellList widget.

However, I can't seem to wrap my head around the rendering of the repeatable part within the cells. Since the cell renderer doesn't bind to anything that I can post process in the Java code it seems like the only way to configure it would be to pass an HTML snippet to it. It feels like a hck and I don't even thing GWT would let me do that kind of thing.

Surely there must be a more workable solution. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to first render your "list of tags" (using one `UiRenderer` called for each item of the list for instance), and then pass that rendered list to the `UiRenderer` for the cell itself.

It might feel *strange* to you but it makes UiBinder/UiRenderer simpler under-the-hood.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Actually I had been playing with this strategy but I didn't manage to pass the HTML as a parameter without it being sanitized to death. Also, I wasn't sure if I was going down a blind alley but at least now I know it's fine.

BTW, if anyone else has problems passing HTML to a UIRenderer, here's how: In the renderer, declare the element as SafeHtml using <ui:with field='someHtml' type='com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml'/>. Then insert it using <ui:safehtml from='{someHtml}'/>. And of course declare the element as SafeHtml in the renderer interface.